# Dynamically add new element to specific list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, sorting

In my Rails 4 application I have a `Task` model which can be sorted/grouped in various ways (group by user, group by transaction, order by due date, etc...) on several different pages. Users can create a new `Task` via an AJAX popup modal from anywhere in the application, and if they are on a page that is displaying a list of tasks, I would like to append the task to the list if appropriate.

```
# NOTE: tasks should only ever be displayed one of the ways below, not multiple

# Displaying tasks grouped by user

<div id="user-1-tasks">
  <div class="task">...</div>
  ...
</div>
<div id="user-2-tasks">
  <div class="task">...</div>
  ...
</div>

# Displaying tasks grouped by transaction

<div id="transaction-1-tasks">
  <div class="task">...</div>
  ...
</div>
<div id="transaction-2-tasks">
  <div class="task">...</div>
  ...
</div>

# Displaying all tasks together (ordered by due date)

<div id="tasks">
  <div class="task">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

The logic for determining which proper list to update is complex, because there may not be any list on the page (no update) or it could be sorted in several different ways like the examples I list above. It all depends on what page the user was on when they created the `Task` and how they had their tasks sorted (if any).

I came up with a "hack", whereby I pass all the possible DOM IDs that can be updated in a specific order and it updates the proper one on the page, or none if there aren't any.

Calculating what page the user is currently viewing and how the list is sorted is complicated, so it seemed much simpler to tell the JS to update "all" of the lists, knowing that only 1 should be present on the DOM at a time. The order of the DOM IDs is important, using the most-specific first and the fallback option last.

Note I am using server-generated JS via Rails' `js.erb`.  I'm aware of the discussion surrounding this practice, but for this application it was much cleaner to maintain 1 copy of my HTML templates on the server instead of trying to do it all client-side and pass JSON back and forth.

```
# app/models/task.rb
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :transaction

  def domids_to_update
    "#transaction-#{transaction.id}-tasks, #user-#{user.id}-tasks, #tasks"
  end
end

# app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  # Only one of several pages that can display tasks a variety of ways
  def index
    if params[:sort] == "by-transaction"
      @tasks = Task.includes(:transaction).group_by(&:transaction_record)
    elsif params[:sort] == "by-user"
      @tasks = Task.includes(:user).group_by(&:user)
    else # default is order by due date
      @tasks = Task.order(:due_date)
    end
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params.merge(user: current_user))
    # create.js.erb
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(
      :title,
      :transaction_id,
      :due_date
    )
  end
end

# app/views/tasks/create.js.erb
$("<%= @task.domids_to_update %>").append("<%=j render(partial: 'tasks/task', locals: { task: @task } %>");
```

As crazy as it seems, this actually works, because there "should" only be 1 of the lists present on the page at a time.

However, when I do things that seem crazy, it's usually because they are.

Is there a way to tell jQuery (or even with plan JavaScript) to only update the first occurrence of the `@task.domids_to_update`? The returned IDs are in a specific order, with the most specific first and the catch-all at the end.

Or is there a better way to implement the functionality I'm trying to achieve?

I'm slowly trying to remove my jQuery dependency, so my preference is vanilla JavaScript solutions. I only need to support modern browsers, so I don't have to worry about IE6, etc.

Or if the solution is resolved server-side by calculating the appropriate list ID to update I'm open to that as well.

Comment: As far as I am aware, using ID as selector will only affect the first actual occurrence on the DOM. Or you could request first by `#this_id:first, #that_id:first`

Comment: Or if you want first of any, use `.first()`

Comment: @RubyRacer: I was more concerned about it updating the second/third IDs I pass it rather than multiple instances of the same ID.  For instance, I'm concerned that `$("#id-1, #id-2, #id-3").append(...)` would update `#id-1` AND `#id-2`; but that's what it's supposed to do.  I was trying to see if there was a way that this code would ONLY run on the first ID it finds. For instance, if `#id-2` and `#id-3` are on the DOM, it would only update `#id-2` and not any others.

Comment: I know it's a strange situation, but the alternative of parsing URL referrer code and checking sorted orders seems overly complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use plain js to check for element existence and assign the first existing element to a variable:

```
# app/models/task.rb
# first, in your assignment, lose the spaces and the hashes, 
# to make it simple to convert to array:
  def domids_to_update
    "transaction-#{transaction.id}-tasks,user-#{user.id}-tasks,tasks"
  end

# app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb
var ids = "<%= @task.domids_to_update %>".split(',')
var theElement = document.getElementById(ids[0]) || document.getElementById(ids[1]) || document.getElementById(ids[2])
if (theElement !== null)
    jQuery(theElement).append(...)
    // or with plain js:
        // var html = theElement.innerHTML
        // html = html + "appended html"
        // theElement.innerHTML = html
end
```